# Underscore.js _.extend function does not copy mongoose model properties when they are not defined in the schema?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, underscore.js

Why can I not use underscore(_) extend to update mongoose models where the properties are not defined in the schema definition. Is there a way to get around this?

Node model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var NodeSchema = new Schema({
    label: {type : String, default : 'none'}
}, { strict: false })

mongoose.model('Node', NodeSchema)
```

Node Controller:

```
var node = new Node();
node = _.extend(node, {"EXTENDNOTinSchema":"TRUE"});
console.log("extend: " + node);
node.set("SETNOTinSchema","TRUE");
console.log("set: " + node);
```

Console Output:

```
extend: { __v: 0,
  _id: 50bb05656880a68976000001,
  label: 'none' }

set: { __v: 0,
  _id: 50bb05656880a68976000001,
  label: 'none' 
  SETNOTinSchema: TRUE}
```

Comment: How do you get that stringification? Seems like `set` does something more than property assignment, maybe eventual Schema changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because if something is not in the schema then Mongoose cannot use '[defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)', and this treats  the assignment like any other.

So first off, just to be clear.

```
node = _.extend(node, {"EXTENDNOTinSchema":"TRUE"});
```

is identical to this:

```
node['EXTENDNOTinSchema'] = 'TRUE';
```

Which is entirely different from this, in the general case.

```
node.set("SETNOTinSchema","TRUE");
```

The trick is that Mongoose is smart, and using the `defineProperty` function I mentioned above, it can bind a function to get called for things like this:

```
node['INSCHEMA'] = 'something';
```

But for things that are not in the schema, it cannot do this, so the assignment works like a normal assignment.

The part that tripping you up I think is that `console.log` is doing some hidden magic. If you look at the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console_log_data), `console.log` will call the `inspect` method of an object that is passed to it. In the case of Mongoose, it's models do not store attributes directly on the model object, they are stored on an internal property. When you assign to a property being watched with `defineProperty` or call `set`, it stores the value on the internal object. When you `log` the model, `inspect` prints out the internal model contents, making it seem like the model values are stored right on the object.

So when you do

```
console.log(node);
```

what you are really seeing is

```
console.log(node.somehiddenproperty);
```

So the answer to your question is really, if you have a bunch of values that are not in the schema, you cannot use `_.extend`. Instead, just use `set` because it takes an object anyway.

```
node.set({"EXTENDNOTinSchema":"TRUE"});
```

Comment: Blown away by the comprehensiveness, thank you for taking the time to clear my confusion.